# Using sunspot gem and solr for indexing search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

Using rails 3.0.6 , ruby 1.9.3

Gemfile (pasted as per info needed)

gem 'rails', '3.0.6',

gem 'rake', '0.9.2'

gem 'sunspot_rails'

gem 'sunspot_solr'

gem 'progress_bar'

I have set up the model as such in user.rb

```
Sunspot.setup(User) do
  text :resume_body, :stored => true
  text :job_title, :stored => true
 end
```

and then i have used

```
class CandidatesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @search = Sunspot.search(User) do
      # Full text on resume body and job title with highlighting
      keywords params[:q] do
        highlight :resume_body, :max_snippets => 3, :fragment_size => 120, :merge_contiguous_fragments => true
      end
```

Whenever i run rake tasks such as 
bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex
rake sunspot:reindex

it throws error

Error

```
    bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex --trace
Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-rails (>= 2.0.0.beta.19) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Your Gemfile lists the gem mysql2 (~> 0.2.22) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
Your Gemfile lists the gem mysql2 (~> 0.2.22) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of just one of them later.
** Invoke sunspot:solr:reindex (first_time)
** Invoke sunspot:reindex (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
** Execute sunspot:reindex
rake aborted!
undefined method `solr_reindex' for #<Class:0xb762a7c>
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:1008:in `method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:57:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sunspot-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/class_set.rb:16:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sunspot-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/class_set.rb:16:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:56:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:68:in `with_session'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sunspot_rails-2.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:reindex => sunspot:reindex
```

## Note - The app earlier used sunspot 1.1 and i have upgraded it to 2.1

This is the first time i am trying out solr and sunspot in development , and i have followed all the tutorials too to make sure the installation is right . But still , i maybe missing something . Anyhelp to point a newbie to a right direction would be very much appreciated . Thanks in advance , i very much intend to use sunspot in production too :)

## Update 1 -

```
tail -f log/sunspot-solr-development.log
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:103)
    at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:73)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:117)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromLocal(CoreContainer.java:989)
    ... 9 more

Feb 25, 2014 1:31:54 PM org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter init
INFO: user.dir=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.0/solr
Feb 25, 2014 1:31:54 PM org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter init
INFO: SolrDispatchFilter.init() done
```

## Update 2 -

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.6)
1.9.3-p448 :001 > User.reindex
NoMethodError: undefined method `reindex' for #<Class:0x9910fd8>
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activerecord-3.0.6/lib/active_record/base.rb:1008:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The list of things I always check when Sunspot is giving me crap: did I `rake sunspot:solr:start`. Did I `bundle install`. Did I `rails generate sunspot_rails install`. Also, is there a reason you are using `Sunspot.setup` rather than a `searchable` block on the user model? That's not causing this, I'm just curious.

Comment: Also, make sure you test this very well. Sunspot 2.1.0 changes the packaged SOLR version from 3.5 to 4.2...

Comment: I did try the searchable block as this is an old app that used to use sunspot 1.1 but no luck , also the commands u mentioned fire sucessfully and i get the results too but the searched don't get indexed .

Comment: I am using solr 4.6 with sunspot 2.1 .

Comment: Also wanted to ask , the new sunspot gem only indexes text search ? What about the latitude and longitudinal searches of  particular user ?

Comment: Latitude/Longitude definitely should work - I know it does on 2.0 because I'm using it. Your error looks like the task is trying to reindex something that is not indexable. Does `User.reindex` work from the console? What does `Sunspot.searchable` return?

Comment: Did that , and updated the question . Please check .

Comment: I have indexed other data types too such as boolean and integer , should i exclude them for now and keep just text ?

Answer (score 1):

> This might help you to get ride .....

**Steps for Sunspot Quick Start :**

1. Add this gem to your gemfile

   ```
   gem 'sunspot_rails'
   ```
2. Install this gem using

   ```
   bundle install
   ```
3. start solr using this command

   ```
   rake sunspot:solr:start
   ```
4. For a simple example, consider a Post model with a title field and a content field. We will index these fields as Solr text fields.

   ```
   rake sunspot:solr:reindex
   ```
5. Here's a simple search against the Post class that we indexed above, running from the index action of the PostsController:

   ```
   class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @search = Post.search do
        keywords params[:query]
      end
      @posts = @search.results
    end
   end
   ```
6. Thats all now we can use `@posts` variable in our view for `index` action. Results will come accordingly

> Note: This is just a simplest example to understanding flow and get
>   started with sunspot solr indexing and searching ... there are many
>   other options which should be used according to our requirement.

Comment: Could you summarise what you think will help from the link? Links have a habit of disappearing over time